# How to use chart.setSize in highchart on div resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

[I am having paper component on drag of paper the chart in the paper is not getting resize on div. On window resize its working fine. I want with div resize chart should resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haLBN.jpg)

I am using `reactgridlayout` for highcharts to be rendered along with drag and drop. when the container is dragged the chart in the container is not getting resized.Only on window resize it is working. I need on div resize. I used `chart.setSize(null,null);`

```
_loadSavedChart(){
   return (
      <ResponsiveReactGridLayout layouts={this.state.layout} 
        onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}
        className={this.state.className}            
        rowHeight={this.state.rowHeight}
        cols={this.state.cols}
        initialLayout= {this.state.layout}
        initialWidth={this.state.initialWidth}
        width={this.state.width}
        verticalCompact={false}
        listenToWindowResize={false}
        currentBreakpoint= 'sm'
        >
      {this.state.savedChartinDashboard.map((data, i) => 
      <Paper key={i} className="c3chart" style={style.chartPaperStyle} 
       Depth={1}>{this._renderChart(data)}
      </Paper>
      )} 
    </ResponsiveReactGridLayout> )
  }
```

OnLayout change i am passing `chart.setSize(null,null)` still not working how to make use of `chart.setSize` for chart resize based on div resize.

```
  onLayoutChange(layout) {

   console.log(layout);
   chart.setSize(null, null);
   }
```

It is working only on window resize when on div(container) resize the chart is getting resized

From the below code you can check the component of reactgridlayout for draggable but not the chart in the paper. on window resize its working fine i need with div resize(on draf of paper component).

I need to make use of this in react component instead of in jquery. I have a onLayoutChange method. how to make use of this method in that.

```
$('#resizer').resizable({
// On resize, set the chart size to that of the
// resizer minus padding. If your chart has a lot of data or other
// content, the redrawing might be slow. In that case, we recommend
// that you use the 'stop' event instead of 'resize'.
resize: function () {
    chart.setSize(
        this.offsetWidth - 20,
        this.offsetHeight - 20,
        false
    );
}
```

});

Comment: The quetion is not duplicate the duplicated was window resize. for me window resize working fine i want div resize i have attached an image and edited the quetion once check and let me know.Thanks in advance

Comment: Highcharts are built to be responsive. If you do not define height and width inside the options JSON you provide to highcharts, the chart will take the properties of the containing element. Hence if the containing element's properties get updated then the chart gets redrawn automatically. check how it behaves when you resize the output section in http://jsfiddle.net/xnkvb9Ls/

Comment: where exactly i need to provide width and height for that chart to properly getting resized based on container which is draggable

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-setsize-jquery-resizable/ the same functionality i need in react instead of jquery of chart.setSize()

Comment: You could also check chart.reflow is size is not set and container changes size while chart's size doesn't update. API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.reflow

Comment: onLayoutChange(layout) {

   console.log(layout);
   chart.reflow()
   }

but no change after dragiing i cant able to stop dragged one. I tried with that initially.