# chart.setSize not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

[It is working only on window resize when on div(container) resize the chart is getting resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHwal.jpg)

From the below code you can check the component of reactgridlayout for draggable but not the chart in the paper. On window resize it's working fine i need with div resize(on draf of paper component).

```
  onLayoutChange(layout) {
   console.log(layout);
   //chart.setSize(null, null);
   }

_loadSavedChart(){
   return (
      <ResponsiveReactGridLayout layouts={this.state.layout} 
        onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}
        className={this.state.className}            
        rowHeight={this.state.rowHeight}
        cols={this.state.cols}
        initialLayout= {this.state.layout}
        initialWidth={this.state.initialWidth}
        width={this.state.width}
        verticalCompact={false}
        listenToWindowResize={false}
        currentBreakpoint= 'sm'
        >
      {this.state.savedChartinDashboard.map((data, i) => 
      <Paper key={i} className="c3chart" style={style.chartPaperStyle} zDepth={1}>{this._renderChart(data)}
      </Paper>
      )} 
    </ResponsiveReactGridLayout> )
  }
```

I need to make use of this in react component instead of in jquery. I have a layout change how to make use of this in that.

```
$('#resizer').resizable({
// On resize, set the chart size to that of the
// resizer minus padding. If your chart has a lot of data or other
// content, the redrawing might be slow. In that case, we recommend
// that you use the 'stop' event instead of 'resize'.
resize: function () {
    chart.setSize(
        this.offsetWidth - 20,
        this.offsetHeight - 20,
        false
    );
}
```

});

Comment: check from http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.setSize. Add live sample to debug issue

Comment: in the layoutChange i have make use of same chart.setSize(null,null) no difference i am getting

Comment: Hi Deep can you give your mailid  so that i can show you the issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-setsize-jquery-resizable/
the same functionality i need in react instead of jquery of chart.setSize()

Comment: @Deep 3015 you can see the comment and i have edited the comment and attached the feature i need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use chart.setSize in highchart on div resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912028/how-to-use-chart-setsize-in-highchart-on-div-resize)